# MassTransit -All IConsumeMessageObserver intercept message with MassTransit.Serialization.SystemTextJsonRawSerializerContext

Tags: c#, masstransit

Help!
I have a consumer for receive raw `json`:

```
public class TestRabbitResponseConsumer : IConsumer<Test>
{
    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<Test> context)
    {
        var test = context.Message;
    }
}

public class TestRabbitResponseConsumerDefinition : ConsumerDefinition<TestRabbitResponseConsumer>
{
    protected override void ConfigureConsumer(IReceiveEndpointConfigurator endpointConfigurator, IConsumerConfigurator<TestRabbitResponseConsumer> consumerConfigurator)
    {
        endpointConfigurator.ConfigureConsumeTopology = false;
        endpointConfigurator.ClearSerialization();
        endpointConfigurator.UseRawJsonSerializer();
    }

    public TestRabbitResponseConsumerDefinition(IOptions<TestSettings> options)
    {
        EndpointName = options.Value.ResponseEndpoint;
    }
}
```

And I have some `IConsumeMessageObserver` with different classes.
When I get messages with class "Test", all `IConsumeMessageObserver` intercept this message in `PostConsume` and `PreConsume`.
How not to intercept messages with `SystemTextJsonRawSerializerContext`?

Answer (score 0):

Inside the observer, `SerializerContext` is a property of `ConsumeContext`, so you would be able to access it from that parameter.

Comment: Hi! 

Now in all **IConsumeMessageObserver** observers in **PostConsume** and **PreConsume**, I put a check:

`if (context.SerializerContext is not SystemTextJsonRawSerializerContext)
{
     //some code
}`

Are there other solutions? This is so bad...